# Как добавить скрипту backstretch.js дополнительную функцию - random / случайное изображение при старте

Tags: jquery

Есть следующее конструкция:

```js
$(".parent").backstretch([
  "https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/001.jpg",
  "https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/002.jpg",
  "https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/003.jpg",
  "https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/004.jpg"
], {
  duration: 2000,
  fade: 750
});
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  width: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font: italic bold 120% Times;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Видя пустой стакан, пессимист думает:<br> "Всё выпили, гады!",<br> а оптимист:<br> "Ещё не наливали!"
  </div>
</div>
```

У родительского блока (`.parent`) с помощью скрипта backstretch.js меняется фоновое изображение.

Все работает замечательно, но необходимо добавить скрипту дополнительный функционал:

В данный момент скрипт меняет картинки согласно указанного в нем порядка: 1,2,3,4
Требуется внести изменения (добавить функцию) чтобы при каждой загрузке или обновления страницы первая картинка выбиралась случайным образом, а остальные шли с сохранением порядка, как это указано в скрипте (например: начинаем с 3 продолжаем 4,1,2…  или начинаем с 4 продолжаем 1,2,3…)
Другими словами порядок смены изображения (какое за каким идет) должен сохранится, но стартовать при обновлении страницы с рандомной/случайной картинки.

Подскажите такой функционал вообще реально на jquery реализовать, если да то буду признателен за решение в виде функции, которую нужно добавить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вносить правки в плагины - плохая практика (если это имелось ввиду).
Куда логичнее подумать, как можно извне повлиять на его работу и на "нехватку" в нем какого-то функционала. Например создать функцию, которая будет "перемешивать" наши картинки так как нам нужно.

В данном случае:

- Случайным образом выбираем id из массива (`rand`)
- Создаем переменную в которую через `slice()` копируем элементы из
  массива `images` начиная с нашего случайного id и до конца массива
- Удаляем эти же самые элементы из `images` (`splice()`)
- Конкатенируем получившиеся массивы (`concat()`)
- Отдаем новый массив нашему плагину

```js
$(".parent").backstretch(getRandomFirst([
  "https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/001.jpg",
  "https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/002.jpg",
  "https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/003.jpg",
  "https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/004.jpg"
]), {
  duration: 2000,
  fade: 750
});

function getRandomFirst( images ) {
  const imagesLength = images.length,
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesLength),
    subArray = images.slice(rand);

  images.splice(rand, imagesLength - rand);
  
  return subArray.concat(images);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  width: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font: italic bold 120% Times;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Видя пустой стакан, пессимист думает:<br> "Всё выпили, гады!",<br> а оптимист:<br> "Ещё не наливали!"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не респект, а респектищщще !! Я видимо вопрос не так сформулировал, но я и имел ввиду не переписывать скрипт (к нему вопросов вообще нет, работает как часики), а добавить дополнительную функцию, как вы и сделали в вашем решении. Все работает как и требуется (первое рандомно, остальные по порядку), еще раз огромное спасибо!!

Comment: @Slava, да собственно не за что )

Comment: Приветствую! Вы мне очень помогли вашим решением (то которое выше) со скриптом `backstretch.js`  Не могли бы помочь решить аналогичную задачу со скриптом  `vegas.js`  вот ссылка на вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728761/232533 , Ваш вариант который выше у меня со скриптом vegas не срабатывает (либо он только для backstretch подходит, либо я криво делаю ) Был бы очень признателен за помощь!