# Как добавить к скрипту vegas.js дополнительную функцию - random / случайное изображение при старте

Tags: jquery

В следующей конструкции у блока `.bgchange` с помощью скрипта `vegas.js` меняется фоновое изображение:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.bgchange').vegas({
    delay: 2500,
    timer: false,
    transition: 'fade',
    transitionDuration: 800,
    slides: [
    {src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/001.jpg'},
    {src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/002.jpg'},
    {src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/003.jpg'},
    {src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/004.jpg'}
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
}

.vegas-slide-inner {
  background-attachment: fixed!important;
}

.bgchange {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 70px 0px
}
.bgchange p {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.0/vegas.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.0/vegas.css">

<div class="parent">
  <div class="bgchange">
    <p>И только много лет спустя, обзаведясь женой и многочисленным семейством, Робинзон Крузо понял, что прожил 28 лет на острове свободы.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

В данный момент скрипт меняет картинки согласно указанного в нем порядка: 1,2,3,4 Требуется добавить к скрипту функцию чтобы при каждой загрузке или обновлении страницы первая картинка выбиралась случайным образом, а остальные шли с сохранением порядка, как это указано в скрипте (например: начинаем с 3 продолжаем 4,1,2… или начинаем с 4 продолжаем 1,2,3…) Другими словами порядок смены изображения (какое за каким идет) должен сохранится, но стартовать при обновлении страницы с рандомной/случайной картинки.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать эту задачу в виде дополнительного скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Незамысловатой функцией можно "перемешать" массив `slides` нужным образом:

```
function random_vegas(array) {
  const toBeFirst = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  const arrayStart = array.slice(toBeFirst);
  const arrayEnd = array.slice(0, toBeFirst);
  return arrayStart.concat(arrayEnd);
} 


$(function() {
  $('.bgchange').vegas({
    delay: 2500,
    timer: false,
    transition: 'fade',
    transitionDuration: 800,
    slides: random_vegas([
    {src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/001.jpg'},
    {src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/002.jpg'},
    {src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/003.jpg'},
    {src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/004.jpg'}
    ])
  });
});
```

Comment: подскажите как правильно подключить эту функцию к массиву `slides` ? Желательно наглядно.. К сожалению плохо знаю синтаксис jquery

Comment: "синтаксис jquery" тут совершенно не при чем.  Обновил, добавил пример.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Работает как и требуется, первое изображение рандомно остальные согласно установленного порядка! Отдельное спасибо за наглядный пример!